# How to download+execute a .JS file in python? Won't work for me

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to download+execute a node.js application for windows via python. But it doesn't download. Here's the code I'm using, it works for other files just not .js

```
import requests
import subprocess

url = "https://github.com/microservers/github/blob/main/git.js"

r = requests.get(url)

with open(“git.js”, "wb") as f:
    f.write(r.content)

subprocess.call(“git.js”)
```

Comment: Windows will probably try to run the script with cscript.exe. You need to tell it to use node. Something like: `subprocess.call("node git.js")`. You may need to add full paths.

Comment: But it doesn't even download because it's a .js

Comment: The file downloads fine for me. _After_ fixing the quotes. You can't use "fancy" quotes (`“ ”`). Use regular quotes (`" "`).